# how to change player location ontriggerenter unity 2d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a platformer with two characters and I want it so when they touch it goes to the next level. however, it instantly teleports me to the end of the game help!! I'm new to coding so don't judge lol.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mrglobtransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int level;
    public GameObject player;
    private bool update;
    private void Start()
    {
        level = 1;
    }
     IEnumerator waitforknees()
    {
        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        update = false;
    }
    void knees()
    {
        if (update == true)
        {
            if (level == 2)
            {
             player.transform.position = new Vector3(-42.75f, -31.97f, 0);
             GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameramove>().player = 2;
             
            }
            if (level == 3)
            {
             player.transform.position = new Vector3(-7.43f, -196.2f, 0);
             GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameramove>().player = 2;
             
            }
            StartCoroutine(waitforknees());
            return;
        }
    }
   
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            Debug.Log("sd hfjsgbchgbvds hgvn");
            knees();
            if (level == 1)
            {
                level = 2;    
            }
            if (level == 2)
            {
                level = 3;
            }
            update = true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

ignore the names I'm uncreative. im new to coding there's probably an easy fix that I'm missing.

Comment: Just a few quick advices :
You should not set hard coded values in your code (your new transform.position for example), instead create a variable that you can reuse later. (and maybe modify in the editor directly)
Instead of writinig `if(update == true)` you can write `if(update)` (easier to read and shorter)
GLHF

Answer (score 1):

So some issues here.

First of all

```
if (level == 1)
{
    level = 2;    
}
if (level == 2)
{
    level = 3;
}
```

this means if your `level` at the top is `1` or `2` it will **always** be `3` at the end because both cases will be executed sequencially.

You rather want to do e.g.

```
level++;
// top it to 3
level = Mathf.Min(level, 3);
```

---

Then you are setting `update = true` **after** calling `knees` .. so most probably nothing will ever happen at all.

Why not simply do

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
    {
        Debug.Log("sd hfjsgbchgbvds hgvn");

        level++;
        // top it to 3
        level = Mathf.Min(level, 3);

        knees();
    }
}

void knees()
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case 2:
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(-42.75f, -31.97f, 0);
            GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameramove>().player = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(-7.43f, -196.2f, 0);
            GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameramove>().player = 2;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry this insnt working did you make a mistake??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `isn't working`?